# how do I start in Sitecore Experience Platform

Tags: sitecore-client

where to go and what forum should I follow?
where to go and what forum should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're asking for.  I'll assume you're a developer & asking how to get familiar with Sitecore.  If so, this is what I'd start with.

Take the free developer foundation class.  That’ll get you started.
https://elearning.sitecore.net/Public/ContentDetails.aspx?id=4D65DA79A42744A59B68DAF2895770BE

Then watch the Sitecore Habitat videos. 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1jJVFm_lGnx1MjuBD-GGvwvQUVsckDj_

Then download Habitat Home and see if you can get it installed.  It’s an example site that is built on Sitecore 9.1 and SXA
https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform

Get a 60 day developer license – Form at the bottom of the page.
https://www.sitecore.com/getting-started/implementation/developing-on-sitecore

As far as a forum; join the Sitecore Slack channel. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bAVDgP5-FhFh8ohPchHtifq-rz7EBkuPojAzdEofJyo

Hope this helps.